# Play-Slick: Is it possible to improve this design (pattern) ... and how to call it?

Tags: scala, design-patterns, playframework, slick, deadbolt-2

I'm using Play-Slick versions 2.5.x and 3.1.x respectively. I use Slick's code generator and produce the Slick model from an existing database. Actually I'm shy to admit that I'm DB-design driven and not class-design driven.

This is the initial setup:

- Generated Slick model under `generated.Tables._`
- Generic Slick dao implementation
- Service layer that builds on top of the Generic Slick dao

These are the forces behind the pattern which I temporary called "Pluggable Service" because it allows plugging in the service layer functionality to the model:

- Play's controllers and views must only see the Service layer (and not the Dao's) e.g. `UserService`
- Generated model e.g. `UserRow` is expected to comply to business layer interfaces e.g. Deadbolt-2's Subject but not implement it directly. To be able to implement it one needs "too much" e.g. the `UserRow` model type, the `UserDao` and potentially some business context.
- Some of the `UserService` methods naturally apply to the model `UserRow` instance e.g. `loggedUser.roles` or `loggedUser.changePassword`

Therefore I have:

**`generated.Tables.scala`** Slick model classes:

```
case class UserRow(id: Long, username: String, firstName: String, 
                   lastName : String, ...) extends EntityAutoInc[Long, UserRow]
```

**`dao.UserDao.scala`** Dao extensions and customizations specific to the User model:

```
@Singleton
class UserDao @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider)
    extends GenericDaoAutoIncImpl[User, UserRow, Long] (dbConfigProvider, User) {
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  def roles(user: UserRow) : Future[Seq[Role]] = {
    val action = (for {
      role <- SecurityRole
      userRole <- UserSecurityRole if role.id === userRole.securityRoleId
      user <- User if userRole.userId === user.id
    } yield role).result

    db.run(action)
  }
}
```

**`services.UserService.scala`** service that facades all user operations to the rest of the Play application:

```
@Singleton
class UserService @Inject()(auth : PlayAuthenticate, userDao: UserDao) {
  // implicitly executes a DBIO and waits indefinitely for 
  // the Future to complete
  import utils.DbExecutionUtils._
  //------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Deadbolt-2 Subject implementation expects a List[Role] type 
  def roles(user: UserRow) : List[Role] = {
    val roles = userDao.roles(user)
    roles.toList
  }
}
```

**`services.PluggableUserService.scala`** finally the actual "Pluggable" pattern that dynamically attaches service implementations to the model type:

```
trait PluggableUserService extends be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.models.Subject {
  override def roles: List[Role]
}

object PluggableUserService {
  implicit class toPluggable(user: UserRow)(implicit userService: UserService) 
    extends PluggableUserService {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override def roles: List[Role] = {
      userService.roles(user)
    }
}
```

Finally one can do in the controllers:

```
@Singleton
class Application @Inject() (implicit
                             val messagesApi: MessagesApi,
                             session: Session,
                             deadbolt: DeadboltActions,
                             userService: UserService) extends Controller with I18nSupport {
  import services.PluggableUserService._                           

  def index = deadbolt.WithAuthRequest()() { implicit request =>
    Future {
      val user: UserRow = userService.findUserInSession(session)
      // auto-magically plugs the service to the model
      val roles = user.roles 
      // ...
      Ok(views.html.index)
    }
  }
```

Is there any Scala way that could help not having to write the boilerplate code in the Pluggable Service object? does the Pluggable Service name makes sense?

Comment: This question belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: It is a design question, the code is for illustration ... besides codereview's Scala activity is close to nonexistent.

Comment: I am missing one thing here: why `findUserInSession` cannot retrieve `User` together with `roles` - something like `UserWithRoles(user: UserRow, roles: List[Role])` ?

Comment: @(PawelDolega) There is no `UserWithRoles` in the data model. I have indeed a many to many rel between `User` and `SecurityRole` but it is Slick not JPA and the generated `UserRow` doesn't contain a list of roles. This was an example, the Subject interface requires more than the roles .. so down that path would be more like `UserWithRolesAndPermissionsAndIdentityAnd..And` besides Deadbolt-2 requires the user type implementing the Subject interface which means `.roles` `.permissions` `.identity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the common variant may be a parent trait for your controllers that has something along these lines:

```
def MyAction[A](bodyParser: BodyParser[A] = parse.anyContent)
               (block: (UserWithRoles) => (AuthenticatedRequest[A]) => Future[Result]): Action[A] = {
    deadbolt.WithAuthRequest()(bodyParser) { request =>
    val user: UserRow = userService.findUserInSession(session)
    // this may be as you had it originally
    // but I don't see a reason not to 
    // simply pull it explicitly from db or 
    // to have it in the session together with roles in the first place (as below UserWithRoles class)
    val roles = user.roles 

    block(UserWithRoles(user, roles))(request)
}
```

The elephant in the room here is how you get `userService` instance. Well you would need to explicitly require it in your controller constructor (in the same way you do with `DeadboltActions`). Alternatively you may bundle `DeadboltActions`, `UserService` and what else into one class (e.g. `ControllerContext`?) and inject this single instance as one constructor parameter (but that's probably another discussion...).

After that your controller code would be like this:

```
def index = MyAction() { implicit user => implicit request =>
    Future {
      // ...
      Ok(views.html.index)
    }
  }
```

both `user` and `request` is implicit which helps to pass into into inner parts of your application (which is often the case - you bring `user` object to perform some business logic).

It doesn't get rid of your `PluggableUserService` per se (logic is still there) but it may help you to easier reuse same logic everywhere in your controllers (as in my experience, you need to have both `User` together with `Roles` more often than not in any real application).

EDIT: I got a feeling I didn't quite get your question. You want to avoid boilerplate in `PluggableUserService` or you want to avoid scattering this conversion with use of `PluggableUserService` everywhere, in every controller (IMHO 2nd option is something to be avoided)?

Comment: Don't forget, you can get the user as an Option from the authenticated request.

Comment: @(Pawel Dolega) Thank you! you brought up  are several valid points that will help improving the design , thank you! as per your question. I think the Pluggable Service simplifies very much the usage of the services on the Play-side. I meant if there was a way to simplify i.e. avoid boilerplate code inside the Pluggable, it is basically delegating to the actual service impl every method e.g. it would be awesome if the `user: UserRow` would be implicit and all the methods auto-delegated to the `UserService` without having to write the delegation explicitly