# How can I extend the following implicit-based design to also cover the Option case?

Tags: scala

This question is related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191944/play-slick-is-it-possible-to-improve-this-design-pattern-and-how-to-call). There I can basically attach an interface implementation to a simple case class. The core is this bit:

```
case class UserRow(id: Long, username: String, firstName: String, 
                   lastName : String, ...)

trait PluggableUserService extends be.objectify.deadbolt.scala.models.Subject {
  override def roles: List[Role]
}

object PluggableUserService {
  implicit class toPluggable(user: UserRow)(implicit userService: UserService) 
    extends PluggableUserService {
    //------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override def roles: List[Role] = {
      userService.roles(user)
    }
}
```

and then I can do:

```
val user : UserRow = UserRow(...)
user.roles

// or even nicer
val subject : Subject = UserRow(..)
subject.roles
```

but now I need to be able to do this but doesn't work:

```
val subject : Option[Subject] = Some(UserRow(...))
```

How can I extend the design above to cover this Option covariant assignment?

Comment: UserService is not defined here. What is that? Also, `val subject : Subject = UserRow(..)` this shouldn't work ... UserRow is not a subtype of `Subject`. :/

Comment: `UserRow(...): Subject` ~~> `toPluggable(UserRow(...)): Subject`. It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have an `implicit def` that wraps an existing `implicit` in `Option`:

```
implicit def toPluggableOpt[T](t: Option[T])(implicit ev: T => PluggableUserService): Option[PluggableUserService] = t.map(ev)
```

This works for all things that can be implicitly converted to `PluggableUserService`. It is also able to be easily generalized to any functor (`List` and the like). Given a `Functor[F[_]]` typeclass from the library of your choosing (scalaz/cats/whatever):

```
implicit def mapPluggable[T, F[_]: Functor](t: F[T])
    (implicit ev: T => PluggableUserService): F[PluggableUserService] = implicitly[Functor[F[_]]].map(t)(ev)
```

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
  implicit def toPluggableOpt(o: Option[UserRow])(implicit us: UserService) = o.map(new toPluggable(_))
```